# Missing YouTube API Key in Console - BUT STILL WORKING

Tags: youtube-api, google-cloud-console

I created a YouTube API Key with credentials some time ago. I recently made some changes to it, by restricting it to certain websites. Today, I noticed I left off a website and went into the console to add it. The API key that I had created is not there.

The other websites I implemented this API on are still working, and I can go to the APP and see the actual API listed. It is not the same as another YouTube API I have listed under Google Cloud Console.

I'm am a novice web developer, so I don't keep up with all current developments. Has Google made some changes recently that might affect me being able to edit this particular API? Thanks.